# Ajax on javascript file creates extra apostrophe when passing to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code. What it does is grab the value of textboxes from html once a button is click. This function is called by the button's onClick property. And this data is processed in this function and thrown to action.php.

If I enter for example in one of the textbox the string <kbd>You're</kbd> when it arrives in the action.php. The value of its $_POST variable is <kbd>You''re</kbd> I don't know where is that extra <kbd>'</kbd> is coming from.

I tried to alert the value of the textbox while it is in the .js file and it outputs <kbd>You're</kbd>. So it is coming in between the success function and before it arrives in action.php

My server's magic quote is set to ON btw if it matters. And no, I cannot turn it OFF.

```
function new_submit_data_std_iden(mode){
        var txtID = $('#txtID').val();
        var txtIden = $('#txtIden').val();
        var txtDesc = $('#txtDesc').val();
        var txtReason = $('#txtReason').val();

        varUrl = "./includes/action.php";

        varData = "MODE="+mode+"&txtIden="+txtIden+"&txtID="+txtID+"&txtDesc="+txtDesc+"&txtReason="+txtReason;

        $.ajax({
            url: varUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: varData,
            success: function(result) {
                if(result === 'SUCCESS'){
                    alert("TRANSACTION SUCCESS");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("TRANSACTION FAILED. PLEASE CHECK YOUR INPUT.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please check the browser console.what data is propagating to action.php.

Comment: How do I do that? I am using Netbeans' XDebug for debugging btw.

Comment: use firfox mozilla browser and press f12 key.than there will be a tab "console".here you can see.

Comment: Urgh. Just installed Firefox. And it seems I cannot access it on Firefox due to some security issues. 

Anyways do you have at least an idea why is this happening? It's the first time I had problem with values passed via ajax to php via $_POST

Comment: try: `varData = {"MODE":mode,"txtIden":txtIden,"txtID":txtID,"txtDesc":txtDesc,"txtReason":txtReason}`